# setTimeout doesn't start instantly

Tags: javascript, timer, dom-events

When I put the following function in the head of my document :

```
(function(){
    var d = new Date().getTime();
    console.log(new Date().getTime() - d);

    window.setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(new Date().getTime() - d)
    }, 1);

    window.setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(new Date().getTime() - d)
    }, 10);

    window.setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(new Date().getTime() - d)
    }, 100);

    window.setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(new Date().getTime() - d)
    }, 1000);
}());
```

I have these logs :

> 0
> 401
> 401
> 402
> 1397

There seems to be a delay of 400ms before the `setTimeout` starts. Why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript setTimeout doesn't allow interval under 100 milliseconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8889239/javascript-settimeout-doesnt-allow-interval-under-100-milliseconds)

Comment: In which browser? And all browsers have the same results?

Comment: Works as expected for me: http://jsfiddle.net/bfQRy/ you may experience the 1 and 15 ms due to minimal intervals depending on browser

Comment: not a duplicate, Chris & RCV gave the answer :)

Comment: @fabien - I rolled back your edit which put the answers on top of the question - the answers have their own section below that anyone can add to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript is not multi-threaded - `setTimeout` does not start instantly.  All that happens when you call `setTimeout` is it puts that function onto a queue to be executed when the current execution stack unwinds. In your case, it is taking about 400 ms to get to that point.

See [How Timers Work](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/) for a good tutorial on this. In particular, this quote is relevant:

> In order to understand how the timers work internally there’s one important concept that needs to be explored: timer delay is not guaranteed. Since all JavaScript in a browser executes on a single thread asynchronous events (such as mouse clicks and timers) are only run when there’s been an opening in the execution.

Comment: It shouldnt be taking 400 ms for it to get to that point (especially with the 1000 ms test). Old browsers it should be expected to take 15ms and newer browsers 4 ms

Comment: [Minimum/ maximum delay and timeout nesting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout#Minimum.2F_maximum_delay_and_timeout_nesting).

Comment: Good catch that this is not due to minimum interval time, but the time the engine needs to execute the remaining instructions on the stack.

Comment: It's possible there is other things happening on the page not shown in the example code in the question

Comment: @Chris megawac has a good point that while your explanation could cover the first 3 timeouts, the 1000ms one should start on schedule. Why do you think it experiences the same 400ms delay?

Comment: @Tibos - possibly other code on the page is also calling `setTimeout`, and so that code takes a while, executing between the timeouts here? I'd expect that if this was run by itself with no other code it would behave more as expected, as megawac mentions